# How to avoid splitting on specific text block in LangChain

Tags: python, nlp, langchain, retrieval-augmented-generation, text-chunking

I'm using langchain ReucrsiveCharacterTextSplitter to split a string into chunks. Within this string is a substring which I can demarcate. I want this substring to not be split up, whether that's entirely it's own chunk, appended to the previous chunk, or prepended to the next chunk. Is there a relatively simple way to do this?

For example, the following code:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=5, chunk_overlap=2, separators=[' '], keep_separator=False)
nosplit = '<nosplit>Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...<nosplit>'
text = 'Giggity! ' + nosplit + 'Ahh yeah...\nI just buy a jetski.'
chunks = splitter.split_text(text)
print(chunks)
```

Prints:
['Giggity!', 'Keep', 'all', 'this', 'together,', 'very', 'important!', 'Seriously', 'though', 'it', 'is...Ahh', 'yeah...\nI', 'just', 'buy a', 'jetski.']

Whereas I would like it to print:
['Giggity!', 'Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...', 'Ahh', 'yeah...\nI', 'just', 'buy a', 'jetski.']

The only partial solution I have is to give `<nosplit>` priority in my separators list and then temporarily replace all other separators within the nosplit text with non-separator placeholders, and then put them back in. E.g.:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=5, chunk_overlap=2, separators=['<nosplit>', ' '], keep_separator=False)
nosplit = '<nosplit>Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...<nosplit>'
space_word = 'x179lp'
nosplit = nosplit.replace(' ', space_word)
text = 'Giggity!' + nosplit + 'Ahh yeah...\nI just buy a jetski.'
chunks = splitter.split_text(text)
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunks[i] = chunk.replace(space_word, ' ')
print(chunks)
```

The issue is with this method I can't use character level splitting, i.e. '', as a possible separator for the rest of the document (I'd like to use the default separators list (along with nosplit): ["nosplit", "\n\n", "\n", " ", ""]).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### One-liner with `re`

```
>>> import re
>>> [
    x for y in [
        [chunk.replace("<nosplit>", "")] if chunk.startswith("<nosplit>")
        else chunk.split()  # replace this with your splitter of choice
        for chunk in re.split("(<nosplit>.*)<nosplit>", text)
    ] for x in y]

['Giggity!', 'Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...', 'Ahh', 'yeah...', 'I', 'just', 'buy', 'a', 'jetski.']
```

#### Explanation

Split your text using a simple regex including a capture group, and keep the `<nosplit>` in the beginning for easier filtering later:

```
>>> re.split("(<nosplit>.*)<nosplit>", text)
['Giggity! ', '<nosplit>Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...', 'Ahh yeah...\nI just buy a jetski.']
```

Iterate over every chunk. If the chunk starts with `<nosplit>`, put it in a list (useful for making unpacking simpler later) and remove the `<nosplit>` tag, otherwise split it with whatever method you prefer (I used `str.split` here):

```
[
    # 1-item list, also remove the nosplit tag
    [chunk.replace("<nosplit>", "")] if chunk.startswith("<nosplit>")
    # otherwise, split langchain or whatever
    else chunk.split()  # replace this with your splitter of choice
    for chunk in ...
]

[['Giggity!'], ['Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...'], ['Ahh', 'yeah...', 'I', 'just', 'buy', 'a', 'jetski.']]
```

Now we have a list of lists, and you can just unpack it:

```
>>> [x for y in list_of_lists_from_above for x in y]

['Giggity!', 'Keep all this together, very important! Seriously though it is...', 'Ahh', 'yeah...', 'I', 'just', 'buy', 'a', 'jetski.']
```

I suggest splitting the above in multiple lines to increase readability. I did in one because I am lazy.

Comment: Thanks! So basically just split the strings on either side of the substring independently. I now realize my question didn't fully capture the nuance. For example, if the substring is sufficiently short, ideally it would be in a chunk that contains content on either side of it. Essentially, I'd like the substring to be treated as a single character for chunking purposes, rather than a guaranteed split on both sides. Any way to do this without adding custom chunk size checks outside of langchain TextSplitter?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a chunk that contains content on either side of it" or what the size of a chunk has to do with the splitting. Maybe you can provide some more examples / test cases in your original answer?